# Find a continuous function such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq C|x-y|^\alpha$ doesn't hold for any $x, \alpha$, any$C$ and any $y$close enough to $x$

Tags: real-analysis

Find a continuous function  such that for $\forall x\in [0,1], \forall \alpha\in(0,1),\forall y$ close to $x$, $\forall C $ constant, $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq C|x-y|^\alpha$ doesn't hold.

I have no idea, I have tried to think about the Weiserstrass function, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have an example of a function for which this doesn't hold for a particular choice of $x$?

Comment: what about $x\sin \frac{1}{x}$? it may not hold at $x=0$

Comment: That doesn't work.  Take $f(x) = x\sin(1/x)$ when $x \in (0,1]$ and define $f(0) = 0$.  Set $x = 0$.  For all $y$, 
$$|f(y) - f(x)| = |f(y)| = |y \sin(1/y)| \leq |y| = 1 \cdot |y - x|^1$$

Comment: Yes, I am sorry, that is stupid.......$\frac{\sin x}{x}$

Comment: That also fails.  Here's one that works:
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
e^{-1/x} & x \in (0,1]\\
0 & x = 0
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: It is not clear that this idea can be extended to give a function where the condition fails at every point, but perhaps it can be made to work

Comment: Yes, how about $f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{|x-r_n|}}}{n^2}$, $r_n$ is the enumeration of the rational number in [0,1]

Comment: I think that will do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one construction that will work: define $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ by
$$
f(x) =  
\begin{cases} 
e^{-1/|x|} & x \neq 0\\ 
0 & x = 0 
\end{cases}
$$
Let $\{r_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ be an enumeration of the rational numbers in $[0,1]$.  Take any $a \in (0,1)$.  Define 
$$
g(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a^k f(x - r_k)
$$
Then $g$ is a continuous function satisfying your constraints.  Continuity follows from the Weierstrass $M$-test, the other conditions follow from our discussion in the above comments.